# NSURL and NSURLConnection do not work with Google Chart API

Tags: api, nsurlconnection, charts, nsurl

I tried to display an image returned by Google Chart API, but the codes below do not work:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World"]];
UIImage *downloadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
imgView.image = downloadedImage;
```

or

```
NSData *imageData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World"]] returningResponse:nil error:nil];
UIImage *downloadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
imgView.image = downloadedImage;
```

The target image was not shown as expected. Do you have any idea where the problem was?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both pieces of code work, except the `NSURL` object is nil. `NSURL` does not support pipe characters (|), so you need to escape it with `%7c`. You could use `[NSString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:]` to take care of any other characters. Here is the new version:

```
NSString *url = [@"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chd=t:60,40&chs=250x100&chl=Hello|World" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
UIImage *downloadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
imgView.image = downloadedImage;
```